# How to test a trained neural network to predict outputs for new inputs

Tags: python, neural-network

New on neural-networks and py and i just started to learn. 
On the web a found this Back-Propagation Neural Network Class that im trying to using for classification.

Link of class: http://arctrix.com/nas/python/bpnn.py

I added to the network 11 inputs with corresponding labeled data [0] or [1]. creating a network with 11 inputs , 3 hidden layers and 1 output.

Example:

```
 # Teach network XOR function

pat = [
    [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1]],
    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0]],
    [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1]],
    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
]

# create a network with two input, two hidden, and one output nodes
n = NN(11, 3, 1)
# train it with some patterns
n.train(pat)
# test it
n.test(pat)

if __name__ == '__main__':
demo()
```

And after the network is trained gives:

```
([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], '->', [0.9931939688547892])
([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], '->', [-0.015507293481101131])
([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], '->', [0.9907311490435106])
([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], '->', [-0.015507293481101131])
```

My question is: **After the network is trained how can I use it to predict outputs for a single input?**

For example i want to predict the label of this new input

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

And give an output for example '0.001212 or 0.99992323'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the test data to the `test` function:

```
n.test([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```